# Problem with managing the Local Storage Data in Angular During Update operation

Tags: angular

My code is working fine with Add and Delete even when the page reloads it's reflecting in my local storage.

But when i click on Edit and press on Update button the data is only updating in my UI , If i reload the page the data is not reflecting in my local storage.

How to fix this issue!!

[image]

this is my HomeComponent.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  name:string;
  DOB:number;
  mob:number;
  gender:string;
  title = 'Employee Information';

  employees = [];

  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";
  addEmployee(){
    let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emp'));
    employees.push(this.model);
    localStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify(employees));     
    console.log(this.model);
    this.model = {};
    this.msg = "Record is successfully added..... "; 
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("localStorage.emp ", localStorage.emp);
    if(localStorage.emp === undefined) {
      localStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify(this.employees));
    } else {}
  }
}
```

this is my ContentsComponent.ts

```
export class ContentsComponent implements OnInit {
  employees = [];
     //{name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"},
    // {name:"Alex",DOB:"23-03-1995",mob:"4558965214",gender:"female"}      
  //];

  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";

  constructor(private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emp'));
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', this.employees);
  }

  deleteEmployee(i){
    this.employees.splice(i,1);
    localStorage.emp = JSON.stringify(this.employees);        
    this.msg = "Record is successfully deleted..... ";          
  }

  myValue;
  editEmployee(k){
    this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;
    this.model2.DOB=this.employees[k].DOB;
    this.model2.mob = this.employees[k].mob;
    this.model2.gender=this.employees[k].gender;      
    this.myValue = k;

  }
  updateEmployee(){
    let k= this.myValue;
    this.model.gender = "female";       
    for(let i=0; i<this.employees.length;i++){
      if(i==k){
        this.employees[i]= this.model2;
        this.model2 = {};       
        this.msg = "Record is successfully updated..... ";
      }
    }
  }
  clickMe(){
    this.msg = "";
  }    
}
```

Comment: update the local storage when you click the update button

Answer (score 1):

```
updateEmployee(){
let k= this.myValue;
this.model.gender = "female";       
for(let i=0; i<this.employees.length;i++){
  if(i==k){
    this.employees[i]= this.model2;
    this.model2 = {};       
    this.msg = "Record is successfully updated..... ";
  }
}
localStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify(this.employees));
}
```

this should work.